# Xampp mysql administration page error

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, xampp

I installed the latest stable xampp package, and received the following error page when I tried to access MySQL administration page.

I haven't been able to find documentation of this particular problem on several guides, and mysql's configuration file, my.cnf does not appear to be in the same place when installed with xampp.
[image]

Comment: Do you have any previous instances of mySQL running? This shouldn't happen in a XAMPP install normally.

Comment: I did try installing MySQL by itself before I learned about xampp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is another instance of mysql service running.

If you are on windows:

1. Go to local services: You can run services.msc
2. Scroll down till you see mysql, right click and click stop on the context menu that appears.
3. Restart xammp and run phpmyadmin again.

Comment: Didn't work exactly, but did set me on the right path :)

Uninstalled everything and did a clean install of XAMPP.